# how to use binded directory in nifi processor

Tags: python, docker, apache-nifi

I am using nifi docker image and I am new to docker. I need to know that if I have binded a host directory to the container then how can I use this directory in the nifi processors. My use case is I have a couple of git repositories and I want to access this repository in the container.
I have used **docker run --name nifi -p 8443:8443 -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=8443 -v /path/to/host-directory:/container-directory:rw apache/nifi:latest**

after executing **docker exec -it nifi bash** I am able to see the bind directories and able to read and write but while accessing this same directory from the nifi I am not able to do it.

Attaching an image (hid the names but I am getting the no directory but this directory exists in the exec command) so I am not sure how to exactly access the directory in nifi executestreamcommand processor. I am getting no working directory exists for /container-directory. Please if anyone can help me out here. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: first guess is permission

Comment: @daggett thanks for your response. I am not having any permission issues. I have already given the read and write permissions. I am just facing the mentioned problem. My guess was the user group but i have already given the 777 permissions and i am using the root user from the start from docker installation.

Comment: `-v /path/to/host-directory:/container-directory:rw` - what `:rw` stands for? show how you are accessing the mounted folder from nifi and what is the error message.

Comment: @daggett rw is the read-write mode though the default is read-write but initially I was getting the permission denied and when I added the rw and gave 777 permission to the directory I was able to touch new files in the directory through the container. I am using docker exec -it <container-name> bash in my case container name is nifi. It opens an interactive console through which I am able to access the mounted folder. Now I got the path with pwd and I used it in the Nifi executestreamcommand processor’s working directory field but I am getting the no such file or directory exists.